# Can terms of a copyright license be void as unconscionable or contrary to public policy or something?

Tags: united-states, copyright, unconscionability

There are things that a contract cannot properly require a party to do, such as committing crimes or pleading not guilty. I think also you can't have a contract that requires someone not to vote.

But copyright licenses are not contracts, and there are many licenses that are revocable, and are automatically revoked under certain conditions.

**Can a copyright license require doing, or punish (via revocation) not doing, things that a contract could not?**

For example, can I license a piece of software only to people who do not vote, by saying that the license is revoked automatically if a person votes? Can I license a short story to be freely copied and read by anyone, on the condition that they never plead guilty to a crime? Or, can I license people to download and view copies of a short film, only on the condition that they do not exercise their right to use excerpts of the work for criticism or parody under fair use?

If I can't get a license like this to "work", do the people I distribute copies to end up with a more permissive license without the unenforceable terms? Or do they end up with no license at all?

Comment: Found where the question went wrong: "copyright licenses are not contracts".  There is such a concept named "license" which is not a contract,  But that's not what you meant when you wrote "copyright license" -- you actually meant "The text that grants a license under particular terms", and that IS a contract.

Comment: What *is* the part of the license that isn't the contract that grants the license?

Comment: Just like an employment contract is different from a paycheck (although it obligates the company to send you a paycheck if the terms are fulfilled) a contract granting a license is different from the license.  But the word "license" is often used to refer to the contract, and that's what your question has done.

Answer (score 3):

### Copyright licences *are* [contracts](https://progressivelegal.com.au/protecting-your-intellectual-property/ip-licensing-agreements/#:%7E:text=A%20licence%20agreement%20is%20a,the%20provisions%20of%20the%20contract.)

At least in common law jurisdictions - they are their own thing in civil law.

Therefore, they can be unenforceable for all the same reasons a contract can be unenforceable.